# Evaluate code within a function call in R (Use ICC::ICCbare within a loop)

Tags: r

I want to use the `ICC::ICCbare` function within a loop. However, the `ICCbare` uses the concrete variable names as input, e.g.:

```
ICCbare(x = group, y = variable1, data = dat)
```

whereby both "group" and "variable1" are columns of the data.frame "dat" (i.e., dat$variable1); `ICCbare`cannot be used with `y = dat[, i]`.

In order to program a loop I therefore need to evaluate some R code within the function call of `ICCbare`. My idea was the following:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  ICCbare(group, names(dat)[i], data = dat)  
}
```

However, this does not work. The following error is printed:

```
Error in '[.data.frame`(data, yc) : undefined columns selected'
```

Is there a way to evaluate the statement `names(dat)[i])` first before it is passed to the function call?

Here is a minimum working example for my problem:

```
# Create data set
dat <- data.frame(group=c(rep("A",5), 
                  rep("B",5)), 
                  variable1=1:10, 
                  variable2=rnorm(10))

# Loop
for (i in names(dat)[2:3]){
  ICCbare("group", i, data = dat)
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are overthinking this. If I understand the documentation of `ICCbare` correctly (didn't install the package), you are supposed to pass `character`s for the column names. Is that not the case? Your example of usage outside a loop seems to indicate that non-standard evaluation is used instead. Is that really the case and doesn't `ICCbare(x = "group", y = "variable1", data = dat)` work?

Comment: Yeah `ICCbare(x = "group", y = "variable1", data = dat)` does indeed work. However, I am not quite sure how that helps for my "loop problem"?

Comment: So, have you tried `for(i in 1:10) ICCbare("group", names(dat)[i], data = dat)`?

Comment: If @Roland's solution works, `for (i in names(dat)) ICCbare("group", i, data = dat)` should work as well.

Comment: Both solutions are -- unfortunately -- also not working for me. They give me the same error message as above.

Comment: At which `i` does the loop result in the error? Does `dat[, names(dat)[i]]` exist? You might have to create a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: I added a minimum working example. `dat[, names(dat)[i]]` exists for both variables in the example. Furthermore, this is not a loop problem. `ICCbare("group", names(dat)[2], data = dat)` also gives the above error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @agstudy. This is a bad example of non-standard evaluation. You can use this as a workaround:

```
v <- "variable1"
ICCbare("group",  v, data = dat)
#Error in `[.data.frame`(data, yc) : undefined columns selected

eval(bquote(ICCbare("group",  .(v), data = dat)))
#$ICC
#[1] 0.8275862
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in `ICCbare` that try to to manage arguments as `name` in a bad manner.

```
function (x, y, data) 
{
  ICCcall <- Call <- match.call()
  xc <- as.character(ICCcall[[2L]])  ## this is ugly!
  yc <- as.character(ICCcall[[3L]])  
  inds <- unique(data[xc])[[1]]
  tdata <- data.frame(data[yc], data[xc])
```

Personally I would remove the first lines and just use assume that arguments are just column names.

```
ICCbare_simple <- 
function (xc, yc, data) 
{
  ## remove lines before this one 
  inds <- unique(data[xc])[[1]]
  ## the rest of the code 
  .....
}
```

Comment: Both answers are a good solution. However, I accepted Roland's one since it is a good work around and does not need any changes made within ICCbare. Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: @phx You should report this to the package maintainer. They should fix this.

Comment: I also already mailed the package maintainer. He might change the argument management in his functions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of `ICC` and I want to thank you for the excellent discussion. I know this is a very late reply, but I just updated the package and the new version (`v2.3.0`) should fix the "ugly" code and the problem encountered by the OP. See examples in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewwolak/daeb12a84bfef88a8c8e).

I just wanted to post this here in case anyone was searching with a similar problem. Thanks again, sorry for the delay.

Here is the content of the gist:

---

## ICC non-standard evaluation examples

The [ICC](https://github.com/matthewwolak/ICC) package for [R](http://www.r-project.org) calculates the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) from a one-way analysis of variance. Recently, the package was updated to better execute R's non-standard evaluation within each function (version 2.3.0 and higher). The package functions should now be able to handle a range of possible scenarios for calling the functions in, what I hope, is a less grotesque and more standard way of writing R functions. To demonstrate, below are some of those scenarios. Note, the examples use the `ICCbare` function, but the way in which the function arguments are supplied will apply to all of the functions in `ICC`.

First, load the package (and make sure the version is >2.3.0)

```
library(ICC)
packageVersion("ICC")
```

### Columns of a `data.frame`

Here we supply the column names and the `data.frame` that contains the data to calculate the ICC. We will use the `ChickWeight` data fame.

```
data(ChickWeight)
ICCbare(x = Chick, y = weight, data = ChickWeight)
#$ICC
#[1] 0.1077609
```

### Iterating through columns of a `data.frame`

In this case, we might have a `data.frame` in which we want to estimate the ICC for a number of different types of measurements that each has the same grouping or factor variable (e.g., `x`). The extreme of this might be in a simulation or bootstrapping scenario or even with some fancy high-throughput phenotyping/data collection. The point being, we want to automate the calculation of the ICC for each column.

First, we will simulate our own dataset with 3 traits to use in the example:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 15                                    # number of individuals/groups/categories/factors
k <- 3                                     # number of measures per 'n'
va <- 1                                    # variance among
icc <- 0.6                                 # expected ICC
vw <- (va * (1 - icc)) / icc               # solve for variance within
simdf <- data.frame(ind = rep(LETTERS[1:n], each = k),
   t1 = rep(rnorm(n, 10, sqrt(va)), each = k) + rnorm(n*k, 0, sqrt(vw)),
   t2 = rep(rnorm(n, 10, sqrt(va)), each = k) + rnorm(n*k, 0, sqrt(vw)),
   t3 = rep(rnorm(n, 10, sqrt(va)), each = k) + rnorm(n*k, 0, sqrt(vw)))
```

Two ways to run through the columns come to mind: iteratively pass the name of each column or iteratively pass the column index. I will demonstrate both below. I do these in `for` loops so it is easier to see, but an easy extension would be to vectorise this by using something from the `apply` family of functions. First, passing the name:

```
for(i in names(simdf)[-1]){
   cat(i, ":")
   tmp.icc <- ICCbare(x = ind, y = i, data = simdf)
   cat(tmp.icc, "\n")
}
#t1 : 0.60446 
#t2 : 0.6381197 
#t3 : 0.591065
```

or even like this:

```
for(i in 1:3){
   cat(paste0("t", i), ": ")
   tmp.icc <- ICCbare(x = ind, y = paste0("t", i), data = simdf)
   cat(tmp.icc, "\n")
}
#t1 : 0.60446 
#t2 : 0.6381197 
#t3 : 0.591065
```

Alternatively, pass the column index:

```
for(i in 2:ncol(simdf)){
   cat(names(simdf)[i], ": ")
   tmp.icc <- ICCbare(x = ind, y = simdf[, i], data = simdf)
   cat(tmp.icc, "\n")
}
#t1 : 0.60446 
#t2 : 0.6381197 
#t3 : 0.591065
```

### Passing a character as an argument is deprecated

Note that the function will still work if a character is passed directly (e.g., `"t1"`), albeit with a `warning`. The warning just means that this may no longer work in future versions of the package. For example:

```
ICCbare(x = ind, y = "t1", data = simdf)
#[1] 0.60446
#Warning message:
#In ICCbare(x = ind, y = "t1", data = simdf) :
#  passing a character string to 'y' is deprecated since ICC version
#  2.3.0 and will not be supported in future versions. The argument 
#  to 'y' should either be an unquoted column name of 'data' or an object
```

Note, however, that an expression evaluating to a character (e.g., `paste0("t", 1)`) doesn't throw the `warning`, which is nice!

[image: Analytics]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I wanted to provide a comment, but because I just signed up I cannot comment on other posts (as @Pino notes). I fully realized it was not an explicit answer, but want the information available in case someone finds this post later on. Sorry if I didn't follow protocol, but in my situation writing an 'answer' was the only way I could do anything!

Comment: I have pasted and formatted the gist contents to make this a more complete answer